# Umbraco 7 Could not load file or assembly

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

i downloaded Umbraco using WebMatrix, after updating Nuget packages it is finally giving error as below

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).

Please suggest where I am doing wrong??

Comment: Do you have installed latest MVC in your computer?

Answer (score 0):

You should download the release version of Umbraco you currently have installed and then add a reference to the 'System.Web.Mvc.dll' that comes in the source files instead.

[Umbraco Releases](https://our.umbraco.org/contribute/releases/)

ps. You can find the version of Umbraco installed by looking for and AppSetting named 'umbracoConfigurationStatus' in the web.config file.